# Good way to check if user turn off bluetooth on android phone for Android application

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to detect whether user turn off bluetooth on their android device through an app.

I tried to use a function to check if BT turn off periodically every 5 seconds

```
private fun checkBluetoothStatePeriodically() {
        // Use coroutines to periodically check Bluetooth state
        advertisingJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(5000) // Check every 5 seconds
                if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled && isAdvertising) {
                    // Bluetooth is turned off and advertising is active, stop advertising
                    Log.d(TAG,"checking...")
                    stopAdvertising()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and it is called in **onCreate()** function of the **MainActivityclass**.

I wonder if that a good practice, I also saw an app where it can detects almost instantly when BT is turned off by user. I wonder if it just about the delay time or there some way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the broadcast action [ACTION_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) that will listen for when it has been enabled/disabled instead of polling every 5 seconds. This will only work while your app is running and cannot be declared in the manifest